# Creating a folder when user clicks on button on web page

Tags: php, web

I want to create folder when a user enters a text and click on a button. The questions are:

1- Should I use php, html or javascript? I don't know if all of them are capable of that or not. If yes, what is the difference and which one is easier to use?

2- I want to append a predefined path prior to the user's text.

3- Obviously, windows differs from linux. So I need both for test.

The HTML code simply looks like

```
<body>
  <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter the name">
  <input type="button" class="button" value="Next">
</body>
```

I also have defined some css codes in .

Comment: You should be using a server-side language to create folders such as PHP, nodejs etc.

Comment: Where would you like the folder to be created? On your server, or on the user's system?

Comment: @struthersneil: on the server

Comment: If it's on the user's system, you might be interested in the HTML5 local storage API...but that's not the same as actually creating a directory on their system (for lots of good reasons). If it's on a server you control, then at the very least you'll need an HTML form posting to a server you control, running an HTTP service that responds to the form post, carefully sanitizes the input, and creates the folder.

Comment: @struthersneil: can you explain with an example for the server side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need an server-side language to accomplish this. In this example, Ill be using  PHP

create_folder.php:

```
<?php 
// if form is submitted
if(isset($_POST["pname"])){
  // create folder
  mkdir(__DIR__ . $_POST["pname"], 0655); // Creates a folder in this directory named whatever value returned by pname input
}
?>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter the name">
  <input type="submit" class="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

Comment: Shouldn't  be `mkdir(__DIR__ . pname, 0655);`?

Comment: @mahmood Ah yes, it should be `mkdir(__DIR__ . $_POST["pname"], 0655)`

Comment: Well it doesn't work! Let me update the post with your solution.

Comment: @mahmood change `<input type="button"` to `<input type="submit"`

Comment: @mahmood and you get the value of `pname` using `$_POST["pname"]`

Comment: May I ask, how can I return to the html page? currently it goes to `create_folder.php` which is a blank page.

Comment: @mahmood In your php file after all the code add `header("Location:create_folder.php" )`

Comment: @mahmood There is also a better way by submitting the form to itself, take a look at my updated answer

Comment: After clicking on the button, the text input becomes empty (means that it returns to itself). However, no folder is created. See https://pastebin.com/eYdQKSpy

Comment: @mahmood I have tested your pastebin code and all seems to be working fine

Comment: @mahmood try adding all your php code before the `<html>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You cant do this by using HTML or Javascript, you need to use server-side languages such as PHP.

And you need to posting form to your php file and look at mkdir function.

```
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir" . $_POST["directoryName"], 0700);
```

`"/path/to/my/dir" . $_POST["directoryName"]` replace with your directory

`0700` is the `chmod` setting for this directory.

Comment: I can not test that on WAMP64 on windows.

Comment: Also, where should I put the php code? I want to call the related function when the button is pressed.

Comment: Yes we cant post all the codes here. You need to learn PHP Basics firstly.For example you should do post variables from forms to php.You should get this variables as well.

Comment: You concatenate with `.` and not a `+`

Answer (score 1):

@sefa is right you can only do this with a server side language like ASP.NET and php. Here's a sample php code.

```
<?php
    //first make sure the directory doesn't already exist
if(!file_exists('/directory/path/')){
mkdir('new/directory/path',0755,true);
}
?>
```